# Android FragmentTransaction, ActionBar Tabs, and Multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

So, I am building a tablet app with the compatibility library and have run into an oddity I can't seem to figure out.  All in one activity, I have 2 tabs (Tab A and Tab B), and 3 Fragments (Fragments A1, A2, and B).  The ActionBar.TabListener associated with Tab A handles the adding and removing of Fragments A1 and A2, and the ActionBar.TabListener associated with Tab B handles the adding and removing of Tab B.  So far so good.

The strange behavior is exhibited when I launch the activity (so Tab A is selected and Fragments A1 and A2 are displayed from left to right, correctly) click on Tab B (so Fragments A1 and A2 are removed and Fragment B is shown, still correctly) and then click back on Tab A!
Now, Fragments A1 and A2 are showing, but in the reversed order: A2 and then A1!

Has anyone experienced this oddity?  If I select Tab B and then Tab A again, they reverse again to be in the correct order, and the cycle continues.  According to [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), "If you're adding multiple fragments to the same container, then the order in which you add them determines the order they appear in the view hierarchy", which strangely doesn't seem to be the case now does it.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to this article, "If you're adding multiple fragments to the same container, then the order in which you add them determines the order they appear in the view hierarchy", which strangely doesn't seem to be the case now does it.

Personally, I wouldn't count on that.

For example, let's assume that you are using a horizontal `LinearLayout`. Your current code presumably is putting both fragments in the `LinearLayout`. The way I approach it is to have two `FrameLayouts` already in the `LinearLayout`, and to put each fragment in one of the `FrameLayouts`.

Comment: Hmm, that is a great idea!  And then when you want to only display one Fragment, just hide (set the weight to 0) the second FrameLayout!  I will have to try this ASAP (am onto another project right now).  Any idea why you don't think we can count on what the documentation says? Is it simply because there is a bug or do you think there is something actually logical about the way FragmentTransactions are working?

Comment: @Shep Shapard: "Any idea why you don't think we can count on what the documentation says?" -- because the sample code I've seen doesn't rely upon that quoted statement. Beyond that, it's just a gut feeling.

Comment: Yeah... working on the "cutting edge" gets pretty annoying because your dealing with undocumented oddities left and right.  By the way, your solution worked!  Thanks!

Comment: Could someone tell me how it is possible to add multiple fragments to a ActionBar tab that is a fragment itself? (Tab A Fragment with Fragment A1 and A2) I thought nesting is not allowed...?

Comment: @and-dev: Nesting of fragments isn't supported.

Comment: @CommonsWare So there is no way to have ActionBar tabs + having the content of one tab including several fragments? I have searched for hours and haven't found a way that allows me to have multiple ActionBar tabs (that can be paged with a ViewPager) + having one tab containing more than one fragment. Do you know a way how to achieve that goal?

Comment: @and-dev: "So there is no way to have ActionBar tabs + having the content of one tab including several fragments?" -- sure there is. You just can't say that the contents of an individual action bar tab is a single fragment holding onto other fragments. Nobody is pointing a gun at your head forcing you to use the `FragmentTransaction` passed to your `TabListener`. Do something else to affect changes to your UI when the tabs are selected.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok understood. Do you know of any example implementing the thing you mentioned? I only found ActionBar tab + ViewPager implementations that build on Fragments per tab.